# clang-format: add spaces after ( and before ) only for ControlStatements(for/if/while...)

Tags: c++, clang-format

I'm using clang-format to format code.
I would like to know if it is possible to add space after ( and before ) only for control statements like for/while/if.

I have tested SpacesInParentheses but it applies to all parentheses:

```
for( int i=0; i<10; i++ )
{
  fct( a, b );
}
```

I would like something like this:

```
for( int i=0; i<10; i++ )
{
  fct(a, b);
}
```

Comment: I do not see anything like that in [documentaton](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html).

Comment: A year later, the documentation at https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html now shows a new `SpacesInConditionalStatement` which looks like it will do what you want.